# Can't login with facebook using quickblox(iOS)

Tags: ios, facebook, quickblox

I'm trying to implement facebook login using quickblox API.

I was running sample app and it works fine for me. But when I'm trying to provide my application info something weird happens: I see facebook login dialog but when I'm trying to login I receive 422 or 401 error. I think there might be some issue with setting up facebook application but I can't get which params should I setup in facebook admin. Can someone point me what fields should be filled and with what values? Information on regular quickblox guide seems to be outdated.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://quickblox.com/developers/Social_Networks_Integration_Manual) is a guide how to setup the Facebook application for `QuickBlox`.

Comment: I've tried that. But facebook admin looks really different now. I just don't get where should I post the callback..Also I've add it to Oath2 section and it seemed to work but I keep getting 422 or 401 error. On Sample app everything works fine so issue is in the way I configured everything.